# SumIfs() not working for a value between a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to solve an exercise with the `SumIfs()` formula (mine is in Spanish) but I can't make it to work correctly....

The first table (ID and price) has all values and I want to sum all values from every ID that are between a range of values (from, to) but I'm doing something wrong and don't know what....

[image: Worksheet]

Thanks for your valuable help!
regards,
Daniel

Comment: Taking a look at your data, if the screenshot has all the records for `OFGEO` then your formula is correctly returning 0 as there are no IDs that equal `OFGEO` that have a value between `902` and `930`. The same is the case for the data I can see for `OIOCMM` and `OBMMSE`

Comment: If you **do** have some records that match the criteria, but you always get zero, then it may be that column B is text formatted. Test by using `CONTAR` function (which only counts numbers)- what result do you get with `=CONTAR(B2:B16284)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula looks fine, what appears to be the problem is the FROM and TO parameters.

For example:

For OBMMSE FROM if you change the 2721 to 2721000 and For OBMMSE To if you change the 2779 to 27790000 you will get a result of 65154250 which is the total B3+B4+B6+B7

This tells me the formula is correct or working but the data in column B is outside the parameters for FROM and TO for each ID.

Hope this helps.

BTW this in effect is the same answers as  guitarthrower